# How to connect SQL Server from play 2.4.6

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I am new to Play framework.
I have problem in connection of sql server from play 2.4.6.

File `application.conf` as bellow

```
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/DBNAME",
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver,
db.default.user=sa,
db.default.pass=pass
```

I added `jtds-1.2.6 jar` in the `lib` and `libexec` folders.

**build.sbt file as below.**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2.6",
  cache,
  javaWs
)

fork in run := true
```

But when i go to browser at http://localhost:9000/ i get following error

**Cannot connect to database [default]**

please help me any one.

Following is detailed Exception:

! @700ahko28 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
application -

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.]

Comment: Check the complete stack trace

Comment: I think the comma in the end of each line in application.conf is too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem with a new Play!2 app that I created in IntelliJ 2016. I copied the configuration from an existing (older) application  accessing the same development server, and was working. But when I ran it in the new project it no longer worked and produced a very similar stack trace.

After much Googling and multiple configuration variations I discovered this link: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/497. When I tried adding the following tot he application.config suddenly everything worked:

```
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct properties to use are `username` instead of `user` and `password` instead of `pass`.

The properties are [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/resources/reference.conf)

Also, you don't need commas in your application.conf file. Once you have mentioned `jtds` in `libraryDependencies` you don't need to manually put them in lib or somewhere else. SBT will pull them and put them in classpath.

Comment: I done all setup as you said but i got error=> Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
 
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]

Comment: It is not able to connect to database, please check all your properties like url, username and password.. all case sensitivity.

Comment: Its not working. all is ok. I am using play 2.5.3 version. is this conf ok to this version? ehat i am doing wrong?  Error is =>  ! @700aggpoj - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
 
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
 com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)

Comment: Could you provide the whole exception trace? and your modified application.conf

Comment: Did you test with any sql client like squirresql.. Also, try using `localhost` instead `127.0.0.1`. I am thinking it is rather a db setup/connectivity issue than a Play issue.

Comment: Connection work with microsoft sql driver sqljdbc4.jar but i want connection with jtds driver. I have edited my quesion with detailed exception.