# For SqlServer please explicitly choose either sqlserver16 or sqlserver17 as the platform via DatabaseConfig.setDatabasePlatformName

Tags: java, sql-server, scala, jdbc, sbt

I am working on Java Play Framework template 2.8.13 with sbt 1.6.2 and Scala 2.13.8 and I come from an upgrade play from 2.1.5 to the mentioned. The problem is when I try to connect to SQL Server (SQL Server Management Studio v18.4 with server version 14.0.1000.169)

**My application.conf:**

```
play.db {

  config = "db"
  default = "default"
  
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    hikaricp.minimumIdle = 5
    hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 5
  }
}


db {
    default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1" 
    default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
    default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/dbName" 
    default.username="sa"
    default.password="test12"
    default.databasePlatformName="sqlserver17"
    default.logstatements=true
}

ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

**My plugin.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.15")
addSbtPlugin("org.foundweekends.giter8" % "sbt-giter8-scaffold" % "0.13.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" %% "sbt-play-ebean" % "6.2.0-RC4")
```

**My build.sbt**

```
name := """PRECIEMSA"""
organization := "com.ciemsa"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

libraryDependencies +=  guice
libraryDependencies +=  ehcache
libraryDependencies +=  javaJdbc
libraryDependencies +=  jdbc


libraryDependencies +=  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "5.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ebean" % "6.2.0-RC4"
libraryDependencies +=  "net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.3.1"
```

**My Global.java**

```
@Singleton
public class Global{

    @Inject
    public Global(Database pDb) {
        this.db = pDb;
    }

}
```

I already tried

- Verify the connection to SQL > OK
- new driver like:

```
db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;databaseName=dbName"
db.default.username=sa
db.default.password="test12" 
db.default.logSql=true
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1"
```

and variants.  This last is running on one older version of project with play 2.1.5

No idea how can connect now.

So, maybe someone have an example application.conf for SQL Server?

**Stack trace error.**

```
2022-05-23 13:55:52 [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36mp.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler[0;39m [35m[0;39m 

! @7nm0g1542 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
 
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For SqlServer please explicitly choose either sqlserver16 or sqlserver17 as the platform via DatabaseConfig.setDatabasePlatformName. Refer to issue #1340 for more details
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:36)
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.class(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:33)
  while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions
  at play.db.ebean.EbeanModule.bindings(EbeanModule.java:21):
Binding(class play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions to ConstructionTarget(class play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)
  while locating play.api.db.evolutions.DynamicEvolutions
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For SqlServer please explicitly choose either sqlserver16 or sqlserver17 as the platform via DatabaseConfig.setDatabasePlatformName. Refer to issue #1340 for more details
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.create(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:70)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.setDatabasePlatform(DefaultContainer.java:215)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:99)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:35)
    at io.ebean.DatabaseFactory.createInternal(DatabaseFactory.java:130)
    at io.ebean.DatabaseFactory.create(DatabaseFactory.java:78)
    at io.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:50)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.lambda$start$2(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:50)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.start(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:50)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.<init>(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:39)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions$$FastClassByGuice$$52c94231.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:213)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:155)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$2(DevServerStart.scala:193)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:22)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:185)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:148)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:302)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:224)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1307)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:542)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:496)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:390)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:521)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:625)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:800)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:818)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:716)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: For SqlServer please explicitly choose either sqlserver16 or sqlserver17 as the platform via DatabaseConfig.setDatabasePlatformName. Refer to issue #1340 for more details
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.byDatabaseMeta(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:153)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.byDataSource(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:135)
    at io.ebeaninternal.server.core.DatabasePlatformFactory.create(DatabasePlatformFactory.java:67)
```

Comment: Your SQL Server Management Studio version is irrelevant, and it is better to use the colloquial version name (SQL Server 2017) than the technicaly version number (14.0.1000.169). In any case, the error (which you really should repeat in the body of your question), suggests there is a piece of configuration missing. Could you edit your question to include the full exception stacktrace

Comment: I know zero about Play Framework, but a bit of searching lead me to [this issue](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/1340), which seems to suggest you need to add `ebean.default.databasePlatformName=sqlserver17` to your configuration (but that is just a guess on my part)

Comment: thanks @MarkRotteveel for your answer but already try that one databasePlatformName
Update the post with another error.

Comment: why you have different versions of mssql-jdbc in your libs? Try to provide a minimum example of project (and libs) which reproduce this error. Do you inject play.db.Database?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin update the question. Please review

Comment: Refer to issue #1340 for more details -- https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/issues/1340
I think you can try to define `ebean.default.databasePlatformName=sqlserver17` or `ebean.yourDataSourceName.databasePlatformName=sqlserver17`. See also [here](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/blob/d98c49e266f5d5e7fcd1e17c48836b03cd39c1e3/ebean-test/testconfig/ebean-db2.properties) and [here](https://github.com/ebean-orm/ebean/search?q=databasePlatformName). Also there is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893305/how-to-connect-sql-server-from-play-2-4-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of struggle on code, web and foros (really 10 days or more) and no solution by application.conf path. I Create a class Conexion

```
public class Conexion {

public static Database ObtenerConexion() {
    
    DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig = new DataSourceConfig();
    dataSourceConfig.setUsername("sa");
    dataSourceConfig.setPassword("sa");
    dataSourceConfig.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbName;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true");
    dataSourceConfig.setDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    ServerConfig config= new ServerConfig();
    config.setDatabasePlatformName("sqlserver17");
    config.setDataSourceConfig(dataSourceConfig);
    
    config.addClass(CategoriaRubro.class);
    config.addClass(CentroComun.class);
    config.addClass(Cotizacion.class);
    config.addClass(Departamento.class);
    //all your models 
    
    Database database = EbeanServerFactory.create(config);
    
    return database;
}
```

}

and called from

```
public class SomeController extends Controller{
static Database db ;

public SomeController () {
    this.db = Conexion.ObtenerConexion();
}
```

}

It is not elegant but it works. May can help somebody.